# Oracle CONTAINS() not returning results for numbers

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-text

So I have this table with a full text indexed column "value". The field contains some number strings in it, which are correctly returned when i use a query like so:

```
select value
    from mytable 
    where value like '17946234';
```

Trouble is, it's incredibly slow because there are a lot of rows in this table, but when i use the CONTAINS operator I get no results:

```
select value
    from mytable
    where CONTAINS ( value, '17946234',1)>0
```

Anyone got any thoughts?

Unfortunately, I'm not an Oracle dude, and the same query works fine in SQL Server. I feel like it must be a stoplist or something with the Oracle Lexer that I can change, but not really sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to `INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT` in general, or the index not having been updated after the looked for records where added (`CONTEXT` type indexes are not transactional, whilst `CTXCAT` type ones are).

However, if you did not accidentally lose the wildcard in your statement (In other words: If no wildcard is required indeed.), you could just query

```
select value from mytable where value = '17946234';
```

which could possibly be backed by an ordinary index. (Depending on your specific data distribution and the queries run, an index might not help query performance.)
Otherwise

```
select value from mytable where instr(value, '17946234') > 0;
```

might be sufficient.

Comment: Hi @Abecee - thanks for the ideas. I actually found out what the issues was. I thought we had CTXSYS.CONTEXT index on the field i was searching, but turns out it was an NLS indexs, which appears toe behave slightly differently... and seems to ignore number strings unless they are currency. 
So I've added an actual CTXSYS.CONTEXT index on there and all is working as expected
Cheers

Comment: @geckojk Glad, it worked out. Still: Please double check, whether you really need the (in general probably) more expensive text index. - If `value like '17946234'` does actually return **all** required records, the suggested above queries should be sufficient (and usually preferable performance wise).

Comment: the reason we are using the text index is because that field contains HTML data (quite large amounts too) so using LIKE shows very poor performance.